# Triplicate all digits in a string

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a string containing digits like `"abc123"` and I want every digit to show up 3 times like this: `"abc111222333"`.

Is there a way to do this with `replaceAll("\\d+.*", ???)` whereas the `?` is whatever digit was found?

Respectively, is there anything "better" than this?:

```
String input = "abc1x23z";
String output = input;

for (int i = 0, j = i; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);

    if ( Character.isDigit( c ) ) {
        String a = output.substring(0, j+1);
        String b = output.substring(j, output.length());

        output = a + c + b;
        j += 3;
    }else{
        j++;
    }
}

System.out.println(output);     // abc111x222333z
```

Comment: `.replaceAll("(\\d)", "$1$1$1")`

Comment: Please don't remove your attempts, something is better than nothing.

Comment: Just thought it was unnecessary and misleading for future viewers of the question.

Comment: @Tunaki in addition to your way you can precompile a Pattern, and use that Pattern to perform the same function to speed up the proces (if it should be performance friendly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"abc123".replaceAll("(\\d)", "$1$1$1")`

Explanation:

- `\\d` matches a single digit
- `()` captures a group
- `$1` points to the first group captured by each match of the regex

Comment: @Tunaki in addition to your way you can precompile a Pattern, and use that Pattern to perform the same function to speed up the proces (if it should be performance friendly)

Comment: @n247s `String.replaceAll` does not directly support passing a `Pattern`. How would you use your pattern in that case ? Plus, I think building the new string is  th part that is actually the most expensive for such a simple regex. But in a more general context, you're right

Comment: Doesn't regex object have a replaceall method?

Comment: @sln what do you call a regex object ? I looked at the doc of `Pattern` and this class does not have such method

Comment: @Dici The way to use a Pattern is not to pass it in a String method (as this is obviously not possible) but use it as this instead: `patternInstance.matcher("abc123").replaceAll("$1$1$1");`. The thing is that `String.replaceAll()` is calling this method as well, but instead is compiling a new Pattern for each call (relative expensive) while you can reuse the same pattern for every replacement. And therefore save a bit of performance. And in addition you can hold onto the Matcher instance as well, although the creation of a Matcher instance isn't that performance consuming as compiling a Patter